# Call javascript confirm from code behind more than one time

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In the ASP.NET code behind I compare some existing and new values and need to ask the User if he/she wants to override.  This is done in a loop, for several (more than one) values.  Therefore user has to be asked, for each value, to confirm Yes or No.  I tried (for testing) putting the following in the loop.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "confirm_yes_no", "confirm('please confirm');", true);
```

But it only fires once.

Can it be done and how?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between _client-side_ code and _server-side_ code.  Also, showing dialogs in a loop is extremely annoying.

Comment: The third parameter ("confirm_yes_no") should be unique for each dialog.

Comment: I can't possibly up-vote @SLaks comment enough. Please don't do this. You can use something like check boxes in the user interface and a required field validator for the "confirmation".

Comment: @Mark  Yes, this was what I was missing.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can register the script using a different script key for each iteration in the loop:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < max ; i++) {
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this, 
    GetType(), 
    "confirm_yes_no_" + i, 
    "confirm('please confirm');", 
    true);
}
```

Comment: HashPsi, thank you.  How do you get the result (yes/no) of confirm() in the code behind loop?

Comment: Well that's the difference between client-side and server-side that SLaks was talking about. You would have to store the result of each confirmation dialog somewhere in the form and then re-submit. And that's going to be a pain. You're probably better off Greg's suggestion and add a checkbox to each input that the user can check before the initial form post with something like "overwrite this field with the new value if it already exists".

Comment: @Mark  I understand.  I will consider all options.  Thank you.